# Is there a keyboard shortcut to findviewbyId in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't like to write findViewById everytime is there a keyboard shortcut for it please I am a newbie to coding help me ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As a Matter of fact there is a keyboard shortcut to write `findViewById`

- if you want to write `findViewById` you could write `fb+enter` in valid context
- if you want to write `findViewById(R.id.)` you could write `fbc+enter`

Answer (score 6):

I don't know for shortcuts, but there is a library called **ButterKnife** which really simplifies some process like *findViewById()* or *getRescources()* and many others ;-)

**http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/**

Answer (score 3):

When you type `fbc` you will get live template

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

For other useful shortcuts visit [here](http://mrengineer13.com/top-10-android-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this function as follows:

```
private <T> T $(@IdRes int id) {
    return (T) findViewById(id);
}
```